# Error SPE -0042 while querying a DB from Unix script

Tags: shell, unix, sqlplus

I am writing a simple unix script and querying a database through it.
date=`sqlplus -s ${o_userid}/${o_pwd}@${o_db} << SOFSOF1
        set echo off head off verify off feed off pages 0 lin 120
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
SOFSOF1`

echo $date

After executing although I am getting the time but also getting the following error:
SP2-0042: unknown command "SOFSOF1" - rest of line ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You need an

> exit

before the end of your redirect. At the moment your session is still connected to the database so treats the 'SOFSOF1' as a sql command, rather than as an end of the redirection.

```
date=sqlplus -s ${o_userid}/${o_pwd}@${o_db} << SOFSOF1
    set echo off head off verify off feed off pages 0 lin 120
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
exit
SOFSOF1
```